# Possible list of 4 letter words for this part of a message

Tags: cipher

I'm doing cryptanalysis and I suspect that the message is a substitution cipher with English plaintext. What words could fit the pattern `slls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use 'union' dictionary from [Qat](http://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=1221&ent=Search&dict=5) you get

> abba acca adda affa akka alla amma anna atta beeb boob cttc deed ecce elle esse ette goog immi issi keek kook lccl maam naan noon oppo otto peep poop sccs sees svvs teet toot tsst uttu

so I suppose it depends what you are decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that any palindromic, 4 letter word should suffice:

Here's a [list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_palindromes#Four_letters) that includes words like:
poop, peep, noon, naan, abba

Comment: Only 4 of those seem to even be "usable" English words too.

Comment: thanx I will try the list

Comment: There's also [`teet`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teet#English)

Comment: "boob", "deed", "kook", "noon", "peep", "poop", "sees", "toot"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list using [Qat](http://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=1221&ent=Search&dict=0), a word pattern matcher tool:

`abba anna beeb boob deed ecce esse goog keek kook maam naan noon oppo otto peep poop sees toot`